Has anyone used 2x12 fir as flooring
New member and new "ish" to woodwork
Has anyone ever used 2x12 fir as flooring ? I was recommended ripping down to 3" wide to avoid cracking and cupping - it is grade 1 and love the look of it as is - I'd be more open to 2x6 - I am very remote and this is all.i currently have suitable for flooring
Thoughts or advice would be great
Thanks!!

Haven’t personally done it, but have seen it. Just know that it’ll look pretty beaten up in a few years. If you’re milling t&g, put the tongue lower for extra sandings.

I haven't used it, but it's your floor. You can do as you wish. I have heard of people staining plywood. I think it's ugly, but beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

Many old houses had floorboards that varied in width - based on where they came out of the trunk - minimal working ie clean the edges and fit ie no wasted material to get each board the same width. Seen some floor boards 15" wide.

My folks built a timberframe which used 2x6 T&G flooring spanning about 3 feet between "joist-equivalent" sub-beams, IIRC. That worked fine. It probably didn't start life as framing lumber (would probably have been dried better in the first place than "KD19" framing lumber) but there were no issues with cupping or cracking.
The southern yellow hard pine mill flooring boards we sometimes got as salvage when they were rebuilding parts of the mill were 3x10" from what I recall. The main reason to use narrower floorboards is to have many smaller gaps when the floor dries out in winter, rather than fewer wider gaps. Really old houses (1700s, early 1800s) often have very wide pine floorboards. And heavy wide plank floors were common in old barns, as well (needs to hold up horses and cows...)
You might want to leave as much of the floor as is safely possible loose for at least one heating season so the lumber can fully dry. But wait until summer (humid, swelled board time) to fasten it down or else leave deliberate gaps between boards to allow for swelling.

Thanks ! Was planning on letting them go a while.before fully fastening - they are very seasoned/old but have been stored outside, undercover but we experience a fairly high RH most of the year - got them out of an auction purchase for a ridiculous deal - I may roll the dice and rip them to 2x5 and lay em down the are on 2x12s with 5/8 T and G ply over an 8 foot span (I like to overkill everything- if I had the ability to resaw to 3/4 ish I would do that + TandG + glue em and nail but I don't have that ability at the moment
